# NetworkManager GUI problem

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, system-settings

If I view/edit any ethernet/wi-fi connection profile, the panel is compressed, as seen in the image below. The "Last Used" field is too low in the window. I have two Ubuntu 20.04 laptops showing the same problem.

I don't use a custom theme (I use yaru-light). Font sizes make no difference. Scaling=1.00. Intel video.

I believe this started after some Software Update.

Any ideas why this is happening, and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: E:NOREPRO.  What themes are you using (if any, if you use the standard theme that ships with 20.04 say 'standard theme')?  Any special configuration on your system?  When exactly did this start happening?

Comment: @ThomasWard What is "E:NOREPRO"? I added more theme info. No special config. Using Intel video with stock driver. I believe it started after some Software Update.

Comment: it means "ERROR: No Reproduction"

Comment: My system just finished its updates, I can confirm this is an issue, I think it's a bug though.

Comment: Bug filed as: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1895312  (However, bug reports belong as bug reports, not here on Ask Ubuntu as questions)

Comment: @ThomasWard Thanks for the problem confirmation. Thanks for filing a "possible" bug report... but it doesn't become a "real" bug until somebody accepts/confirms it... so until then, my question is still valid here on AU.

Comment: I had the same problem when I first installed 20.04 and while fixing another wifi issue I found it fixed itself after I launched `nm-connection-editor' to check some more detailed settings. This has absolutely nothing to do with WHY it is happening but it was a happy accident for me.

Comment: This is also happening on Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid with German language set as default and running the default themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in Ubuntu 20.10.